# android breakpoint bugs eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

When debugging an Android application on Eclipse, after I choose 'Resume' (F8), the code stops randomly at some Android system classes which get opened in the code editor (although they lack the source code), like ZygoteInit or other classes.

Has anyone else experienced this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally happens when your app crashes because of an Uncaught Exception. If you hit resume again it spit out the error to logcat. There might be settings in Eclipse to not auto open files with no source, or to not auto stop on exception, but I stopped using eclipse a while ago.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it. Yet this happens to me not only when the app crashes.

Comment: For anyone wondering: Preferences > Debug > Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use Log class to debug your code through LogCat.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I use it frequently, but I also like sometimes to use debugging when dealing with severe bugs. I can watch many expressions and variables at runtime. I would otherwise require a lot of logging to see this

Comment: I see your problems and vote up for this question. Take a look at this link, it may helpful with you. [http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)